# ¿En qué está categorizada la palabra "main"?

Tags: java

Así como las [palabras reservadas](https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_Java/Palabras_reservadas) no funcionan como identificadores; constituyendo una lista conformada por distintos nombres sean de funciones como "accert" o tipos de datos como "byte"...

- ¿Cuál es el género de la palabra "main"? (como se considera o como está constatada).
- Finalmente, ¿Cuál es su rol principal y secundario?, es decir, las funciones con las que cumple.

*Gracias por leer hasta el final, lo siento por la simplicidad de la pregunta pero a que está interesante, ¿no?*

Buen día,
Steven

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La palabra `main` en Java no es una palabra reservada.

Podemos utilizarla como nombre de variable:

```
public class MiClase {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x=10;
        int y=25;
        int main=x+y;

        System.out.println("La operacion x+y = " + main);
    }
}
```

También podemos utilizarla como nombre de otros métodos:

```
public class MiClase {

    private static void main(String mensaje)
    {
        System.out.println(mensaje);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x=10;
        int y=25;
        int main=x+y;

        main("La operacion x+y = " + main);
    }
}
```

Sin embargo, su importancia radica en que funciona como el punto de inicio del programa para poder ser ejecutado por la máquina virtual (JVM). De otra forma, ¿cuál método empezaría ejecutando la JVM? Si no tenemos el método main, por ejemplo:

```
public class MiClase {

    private static void main(String mensaje)
    {
        System.out.println(mensaje);
    }

    public static void main2(String args[]) {
        int x=10;
        int y=25;
        int main=x+y;

        main("La operacion x+y = " + main);
    }
}
```

la ejecución nos devolverá el siguiente error:

> Main method not found in class MiClase, please define the main method
>   as:    public static void main(String[] args)

¿Pero por qué nos dió el error si tenemos un método `main(String mensaje)` ? Esto es porque la JVM busca siempre el método `public static void main(String[] args)` o alguna de sus **variantes*** como punto de inicio, ignorando los demás.

Si tan solamente variamos el tipo de acceso del método main de público a privado tendremos el mismo error:

```
public class MiClase {

    private static void main(String mensaje)
    {
        System.out.println(mensaje);
    }

    private static void main(String args[]) {
        int x=10;
        int y=25;
        int main=x+y;

        main("La operacion x+y = " + main);
    }
}
```

> Error: Main method not found in class MiClase, please define the main
>   method as:    public static void main(String[] args)

***Variantes** que si reconoce la JVM (entre otras):

```
static public void main(String args[])
public static final void main(String args[])
public static final void main(String... args)
```

Lo común en todas es que debe ser `static` porque permite que el método main sea ejecutado sin haber instanciado a la clase padre (en este caso MiClase), `public` porque puede ser accedido desde cualquier lugar afuera de la clase, y `void` indica que no devuelve ningún valor.

Sin embargo, tampoco podemos ejecutar una clase con dos variantes del método main que si reconoce la JVM como punto de inicio, porque sería ambiguo cuál ejecutar primero. Por ejemplo:

```
public class MiClase {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("hola");
    }
    public static final void main(String... args) {
        int x=10;
        int y=25;
        int main=x+y;

        System.out.println("La operacion x+y = " + main);
    }
}
```

Nos devuelve el siguiente error:

> /MiClase.java:5: error: cannot declare both main(String...) and
>   main(String[]) in MiClase
>       public static final void main(String... args) {

Comment: Muchas gracias 

Comment: Excelente explicación, pero como se la definiría concretamente, digamos esto: "." = sería un modificador de acceso y esto: "main" = sería...?

Comment: una palabra como cualquier otra. Como cliente, persona, archivo, etc. Pero, con la salvedad que la JVM buscará siempre el método main para iniciar el programa.

Comment: Gracias por responder

¿Le podría dar esta definición? - Umbral para ejecución.
                                                o - Plabra que indica al JVM que se está 
                                                declarando el método main (determinador).